# fragmen'ts onCreate is called every time i switch to it in tabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have some tabs in my main activity, each tab is a fragment.

Now, in a certain fragment I do something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    ... initialization

    DownloadTask dvt = new DownloadTask();
    dvt.execute(new Void[]{});
    dvt = null;
}
```

the download task populates a listview. Now, each time i go back and forth from this tab the task is called over and over, but it shouldn't as onCreated is supposed to be called just on fragment creation. I'd like to call this task just the first time, and then save the fragment as it is, with populated listview.
I checked and I see that onDestroy is not called...so what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the documentation for [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29), if you call `setRetainInstance(true)` on your `Fragment`,

> onAttach(Activity) and onActivityCreated(Bundle) will still be called

so put both `setRetainInstance()` call and the `AsyncTask` starting code to your `Fragment`'s `onCreate()` to achieve desired behavior. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Phate, Why false? Use the same code, but put it inside Fragment's onCreate() rather than onActivityCreated(), that's what I was trying to say.